# Single wp-admin for diffrent domain site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mapping

I have two different domain

1)firstsite.com  ...........  Domain register http://godaddy.com/ and hosting justhost

2)secondsite.com  .......... Domain register http://godaddy.com/ and hosting justhost

Both site have diffrent Cpanel,Ftp,Database

i have installed wordpress both site root directory

**Task**: Make single wp-admin for both site(mean to say operate both site with single admin panel)

i have follow those step do it on **firstsite.com site**

1)First create multisite network setup with help below link

[Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

2)For Domain mapping use below link

[WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

but that setup is successfully working for sub domain not for separate domain(i can include other site like sub.firstsite.com and there is no option for separate domain secondsite.com)

so plz guide me wht i m doing is that correct way or its not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it on the correct way :)

But network administration only manage users / sites / extensions / themes. Each sub site has it own admin for regular Wordpress Admin.

For example my network:

Main website http://basgrospoing.fr

sub sites:

- http://worldgamecup.basgrospoing.fr
- http://kenbogard.basgrospoing.fr
- http://republicofighters.basgrospoing.fr

Comment: so mean to say that's not possible for different domain like secondsite.com

Comment: You can do that, you just have to do a redirection DNS.

Comment: For example http://kenbogard.basgrospoing.fr is also used with http://kenbogard.fr But i haven't done any url rewriting.

Comment: @Zenth, we can create networking only for sub domain and sub directory folder and not different domain.

Comment: @vikastyagi it's true. I was just saying he can do DNS redirection on the domain name.